# $X_i = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = i^2\}$. Show that the collection of sets $X_i$ for $i \in I$ form a partition of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis

> $X_i = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = i^2\}$. Show that the collection of sets $X_i$ for $i \in I$ form a partition of $\mathbb R^2$.

Do we use bijection? Is there any other way to solve it without using equivalence?

Comment: In general, if $f\colon D\to R$ is any function, then the sets $\{z\in D\colon f(z)=r\}$, as $r$ ranges over $R$, form a partition of $D$. This example has $R=[0,\infty)$ and $f((x,y)) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. (It's good to work out that this is a partition directly, for learning about the subject. But it's also good to see that it fits into a more general pattern.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to show:

- The union of these sets is all of $\mathbb R^2$

Hint: to show this, you need to demonstrate that for any $(x,y)$, there is an $i$ so that $(x,y) \in X_i$.

- The intersection of any two of these sets is empty.

Hint: to show this, you need to demonstrate that, for a fixed $(x,y)$, if $(x,y) \in X_i$ and $(x,y) \in X_j$, then $i = j$.

You may want to carefully check your original problem statement, as it is not clear what $I$ is. In particular, if $I = [0,\infty)$, then this is fine, but if $I$ includes negative numbers, then you have trouble (for instance $i_1 = 1$ and $i_2 = -1$ define the same $X_i$.

Comment: I'm sorry. Ya that's what I is. I kind of know the proof for both of these but how to show the union of all the sets is R2. Can you give hints ?

Comment: Ok, I've added some hints.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show two things:

> $1.$For all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ exists $i$, that $(x,y) \in X_i$.

Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $x^2+y^2=a^2$ for some $a$. By definition of $X_a$ you have $(x,y) \in X_a$.

> $2.$If $a \neq b$ the $X_a \cap X_b=\emptyset$.

Let $a \neq b$. By contradition let $(x,y) \in X_a \cap X_b$, so $(x,y) \in X_a$ and $(x,y) \in X_b$. Because  $(x,y) \in X_a$ you have $x^2+y^2=a^2$, by $(x,y) \in X_b$ $x^2+y^2=b^2$, so:

$$a^2=x^2+y^2=b^2$$

$$a^2=b^2$$

$$|a|=|b|$$

But $a,b \geq 0$, so

$$a=b.$$